# Which of the following sets are connected?

Tags: connectedness

- In the set of all $n×n$ matrices with real entries, considered as the space $R^{n^2}$ , which of the following sets are connected?

  > (a) The set of all orthogonal matrices.
  >
  > (b) The set of all matrices with trace equal to unity.
  >
  > (c) The set of all symmetric and positive definite matrices.

*I've shown a is true and b is false since the continuous image of a connected set is connected. But I'm clueless about (c).*

Comment: It seems to me that set (b) is connected. If trace$(A) = $ trace$(B) = 1$, then trace$(tA+(1-t)B) = 1$ for all $t$, which gives you a path from $A$ to $B$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Orthogonal matrices can have deteminant $+1$ or $-1$ and both values do occur. Since the determinant is a continuous map, the set of orthogonal matrices is *not* connected.

The set of matrices with trace $1$ is convex and in fact is an affine linear subspace (with trace$=0$ it would be a linear subspace), hence (path)connected.

The set of symmetric positive definite matrices is readily shown to be convex and hence path-connected:
Let $A,B$ be such matrices. Then all matrices $(1-t)A+tB$ with $0\le t\le 1$ are symmeric matrices and are positive definite because $$v^T((1-t)A+tB)v=(1-t)v^TAv+tv^TBv>0$$ for $v\ne0$.